# Can badges be unearned?

Tags: discussion, badges

For example, say someone gets the Unsung Hero badge for 10 or more zero score accepted answers, and 25% of total.  Now, say someone goes and votes for some of their zero score accepted answers.  Do they still have the badge?  I'm not speaking specifically about this badge, but it's one easy example I thought of.

Comment: See also: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21815/can-an-awarded-badge-be-withdrawn

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<strike>Once you get a badge, it is yours forever.</strike>

**Edit**

For *most* cases, once you get a badge, it is yours forever. The big exception is tag badges. If you no longer have the required score or number of answers in a tag, then a tag badge will be withdrawn.

But for almost every other badge, they are yours to keep once they're awarded to you.

If the badge system changes again, I would expect a cannonical place to read about the new behaviors to be the [How do badges work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work) on Meta.SE.

Comment: I'm not sure that the link is up to date, and I am fairly certain that some changes to the badges system were introduced since then. **Edit:** According to [this meta.SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work) thread, the information is up to date. I wonder how that works with respect to removed votes from account deletions.

Comment: It does mention, however, that tag specialist badges may disappear (at least if I understand it correctly).

Comment: @Asaf: Ah - I did not know that tag specialist badges could disappear. That's good to know. Thanks for picking that up -

Comment: This happened to me, when somebody who upvoted me deleted their account. Still have the badge.

Comment: This happened yesterday, when the Integral tag was eliminated.  I had a silver badge in Integral and assumed it was lost.  Then it turned out that, while I did seem to lose it, I made up for it because the tag was migrated to Integration and I gained a silver (and gold to boot!) badge for that tag.

Comment: The remark about the "next badge" is no longer true see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81013/nice-answer-badge-roulette/187740#187740 or the relevant section of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work Somewhat separately it may make sense to do some duping or merging with http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21815/can-an-awarded-badge-be-withdrawn Or maybe one keeps them separate for the different emphasis on usual vs tag.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in [Asaf's comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6848/can-badges-be-unearned#comment24783_6849), one exception is that tag badges can be removed.

I will copy here the content of [Arthur Fischer's comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11389/on-integration-versus-integral-and-excessive-retagging#comment43119_11389) from another question, where he provided more details:

> The regular badges are never removed (except in extreme circumstances). As the tag badges depend on your scores in tags, they are removed whenever you no longer match the criteria. (See MSO FAQ posts [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17854/214632) and [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63836/214632) for details.)