# Is it possible to lose the electorate badge?

Tags: discussion, support, badges

> [Electorate](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/44/electorate): Vote on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions.

Is it possible to lose this badge after having earned it?

For example, I just earned the badge, and I’ve cast a total of 1,392 votes, which implies that at least 43% of my votes were on questions. If I were to now cast 1,600 votes on answers exclusively, this would change my ratio of (votes on questions)/(total votes) to 20%. Does that mean I would lose my electorate badge?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only badges that can be awarded and later taken away are the tag-badges.

For more details see:

- [Is it possible to lose the Electorate badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/119799) on meta.SE
- [Is it possible to lose badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58053) on meta.SE
- [Can badges be unearned?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6848)
- Not related to the electorate badge, but related to badges in
  general: [Can an awarded tag-badge be
  withdrawn?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21815)

Comment: So it looks like OP is stuck with the badge, whether he wants it or not.