# If conditions change, are badges revoked if the condition no longer applies?

Tags: support, badges

I've recently earned "tenacious", because a fair number of answers of mine have been accepted but have zero score.

However, it is not beyond the realms of possibility that certain of these questions may yet be upvoted, hence causing the number of such zero-score accepted answers to decrease, and drop below the threshold for which the badge is granted.

If this happens, do I then lose my badge? (I confess I'm quite proud of this one.)

Comment: [meta.se]: [Is it possible to lose badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58053) and the section "Can badges be lost/revoked/taken away after they are awarded? If so, how and when?" in the FAQ post: [How do “badges” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17853) And also on this meta: [Can badges be unearned?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6848) AFAIK the only badges that can be removed are tag badges: [Can an awarded tag-badge be withdrawn?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21815)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thank you -- is it appropriate for me to delete this question?

Comment: I have [asked one of the mods in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/83225/2021/3/30) what would be the best course of action - mainly because they point out some time ago that [the accepted answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6848/can-badges-be-unearned/6849#6849) on the older question might be outdated.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thank you, I will await advice.